# AdWords HTML banner - how to start animation when banner is visible?

Tags: javascript, html, google-ads-api, banner, banner-ads

I have created an html banner for AdWords with animate cc. it plays well and it passes the appspot AdWords validator. 
The trouble is that google has a 30 sec animation limit and my banner starts playing when loaded. 
So if the banner is not on screen when the page loads, the animation can be wasted before the user scrolls over the banner.

- in DoubleClick there is Enabler.isVisible
- how do I do that in AdWords?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window Onload

window.onload = function() {

```
//your animation code
```

};

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see how this can help me? As far as I understand the iframe content is loaded when the parent is loaded. So wouldn't the iframe's window.onload be triggered just after the parent.window.onload is triggered?

Comment: Did you try with that? I used it to solve same problem.

Comment: Well... I develop the banners for a client so I can't really see the end result (the banner shown as part of an adwords campaign). But currently the animation is triggered via <body onload="init();" so I suppose this would work the same way as window.onload? (thanks for your advices!)